# Warden - default Encryption strategy it uses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone tell me the default encryption strategy the Warden gem (https://github.com/hassox/warden) uses to encrypt password?

Comment: AFAIK Warden doesn't encrypt passwords.  JIC you're using Devise (which leverages Warden) - Devise uses [Bcrypt](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/encryptor.rb).

Comment: Standard encryption functionality is typically handled with `MD5` or `SALT` on the web